# string.Remove doesnt work

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following Problem:

ive written a programm which uses google image search to extrakt links to jpg files. But in front of link i have a 15 chars long string which i cant remove.

```
    public const int resolution = 1920;
    public const int DEFAULTIMGCOUNT = 40;

    public void getimages(string searchpatt)
    {
        string blub = "http://images.google.com/images?q=" + searchpatt + "&biw=" + resolution;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        string html = client.DownloadString(blub);                                              //Downloading the gooogle page;
        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(html,
            @"(https?:)?//?[^'<>]+?\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)");

        int mccount = 0;                                                                        // Keep track of imgurls 
        string[] results = new string[DEFAULTIMGCOUNT];                                         // String Array to place the Urls 

        foreach (Match m in mc)                                                                 //put matches in string array
        {
            results[mccount] = m.Value;                
            mccount++;
        }

        string remove = "/imgres?imgurl=";
        char[] removetochar = remove.ToCharArray();

        foreach (string s in results)
        {
            if (s != null)
            {
                s.Remove(0, 15);
                Console.WriteLine(s+"\n");
            }
            else { }
        }
       //  Console.Write(html);


    }
```

i tried remove and trimstart but none of them is working and i cant figure out my failure.

I solved it like

```
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (results[i] != null)
            {
                results[i] = results[i].Substring(15);
                Console.Write(results[i]+"\n");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since you know that you want to dump 15 characters you can use substring.

Comment: Note that most of your code is actually irrelevant to your question - and you've got variables in there that you're not even using. (Why are you calling `ToCharArray` at all?)

Comment: i was unsure if my failure woud be in the MatchCollection

Answer (score 33, accepted):

(I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't immediately find one.)

Strings in .NET are immutable. Methods like `string.Remove`, `string.Replace` etc don't change the contents of the *existing* string - they return a *new* string.

So you want something like:

```
s = s.Remove(0, 15);
```

Or alternatively, just use `Substring`:

```
s = s.Substring(15);
```

Comment: thank you :) i didnt knew that